# SwiftUI: Different Widths for Multiline Text Views in Boxes

Tags: swiftui

Here is how two boxes with text are rendering in SwiftUI, but I want them to both be full-width:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
VStack(spacing: 20){
  //Help ---
  VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing:10){
    Text("Help").h2()
    Text("Please view our online user guide before contacting us since we answer most questions there.")
      .lineLimit(nil) //Make the text wrap
      .prefsText()
    
    Button("Online Help"){
      openURL(URL(string: "https://avid.pro/help")!)
    }.foregroundColor(Color(accentColor))
    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
    .prefsLink()
    
  }.unoBoxRoundPad()
  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
  
  //Support ---
  VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing:10){
    Text("Support").h2()
    Text("Email us if you need to submit a bug or get specialized help. It may take us a few days to get back to you.")
      .lineLimit(nil) //Make the text wrap
      .prefsText()
  
    Button("Email Us"){
      openURL(URL(string: "mailto:help@avid.pro")!)
    }.foregroundColor(Color(accentColor))
    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
    .prefsLink()
    
  }.unoBoxRoundPad()
  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

}.background(Color.yellow) //For testing
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why they aren't the same width. `.unoBoxRoundPad()` is a view modifier that adds these shared styles:

```
.padding(20)
.background(Color("UnoDark"))
.cornerRadius(7)
```

If I put `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` on the `Text()` instead of on the containing `VStack`, it seems to get a little closer, but then it disregards the containing view's `padding()`:

[image]

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues at play here:

1. You've got two modifiers swapped (`.frame(...)` and `.unoBoxRoundPad()`); you want the roundedness to apply to the entire stretched thing. By putting `.unoBoxRoundPad()` first, you're saying "pad this thing" and then "place that rounded thing inside an infinitely-wide box"; you want the reverse: your thing should be placed inside an infinitely-wide box, and it's the infinitely wide box that should have the rounded corners and padding.
2. You need to specify an `alignment:` when using that `.frame()` modifier; when the inner view is placed inside an infinitely-wide box, it's going to default to being centered vertically and horizontally inside it. Based on your screenshots, you probably want to use `.topLeading` so that the content ("Support", "Help", etc) start in the top-left corner (or top-right in RTL languages).